# Porting a web-based POS system to Android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm currently porting a web-based POS system to Android. The Android version uses `NavigationDrawer` to navigate between menus.

What I need a code review on is my current approach in loading fragments upon selected an item from navigation drawer. I'm using reflection to achieve my case.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(String menuItemText) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        BaseFragment fragmentToOpen = null;
        Method newInstanceMethod = null;
        try {
            newInstanceMethod = AvailableMenuList.MENU_ITEM_TABLE.get(menuItemText).getMethod("newInstance", null);
            fragmentToOpen = (BaseFragment) newInstanceMethod.invoke(fragmentToOpen, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentToOpen, menuItemText)
                .addToBackStack(menuItemText)
                .commit();
    }
```

`HashMap` implementation of available POS functions in Android version:

```
    public class AvailableMenuList {
        private AvailableMenuList() {} //Disable object instantiation

            public static final HashMap<String, Class<BaseFragment>> MENU_ITEM_TABLE = new HashMap() {{
                put("Announcement", AnnouncementListFragment.class);
                put("Board", BoardListFragment.class);
                put("SalesRegistration", SalesRegFragment.class);
                put("SalesRecords", SalesRtvFragment.class);
                put("OrderRegistration", OrderRegFragment.class);
                put("OrderRecords", OrderRtvFragment.class);
            }};
        }
    }
```

Is there a better approach of instantiating a new `Fragment` (by calling `newInstance`) instead of using reflection? Currently, there's only 6 functionalities but there's going to be at least 30 more in the future.

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?

Comment: @barq API Ver 10 and Up

Answer (score -1):

You can use fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() instead.

If the fragment is not found, initalize a new one.

fragment = new YourFragment();

Comment: It seems like the fragments are supposed to be created dynamically, i.e. they don't exist in the fragment manager already, so this is unlikely to be a good solution.

Comment: Why is this a bad solution? I always do it this way.